# Cannot get pod on Bitbucket through Artifactory cache proxy

Tags: cocoapods, bitbucket, artifactory

We have cache proxy for Cocoapods with Artifactory and we encounter a problem with a specific pod ([NAOSDK](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NAOSDK)) .

Artifactory try to force the URL to get the source by using Github but the actual source of this [NAOSDK](https://bitbucket.org/polestarusa/naosdk/src) is on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/polestarusa/naosdk/src).

Has someone already got the same problem?

If yes, did you fix it and how?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have the cache in Artifactory with the old repository for the source (Github) and the actual repository is in other URL (in Bitbucket server) so you need to delete your Artifactory cache for Cocoapods.

When you delete this cache you aren't going to have the problem.